# Introduction to Proof via Type Theory

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, book-recommendation, type-theory, lecture-notes

Is there an introduction to mathematical proofs book that uses type theory instead of set theory? I'm aware of books like Hammack's *Book of Proof* or Epp's *Discrete Mathematics with Applications* but they emphasize the "$\in$" notation and corresponding naive principles of set-theoretic reasoning. I'm also aware of the existence of lecture notes for interactive theorem provers, but i would prefer a pencil-and-paper kind of learning experience of instead the approach using compiled and programing languages. I want to see the classic topics in the transition to advanced mathematics canon being recast using type theory, for example those topics in the subgenre of books mentioned, like the ubiquitous proof of the irrationality of the square root of two, equivalent statements to the well-ordering principle and maybe some epsilon-delta arguments from differential calculus.

Comment: Russell & Whitehead's Principia Mathematica which originated the concept of type theory, could be considered to match your description. But ... there is a reason the book has been called "the most influential book in mathematics that no one has ever read". While the claim is more tongue-in-cheek than factual, it is true that very few people have worked through it, and even Russell and Whitehead themselves lost their taste for the program and stopped working on it after the first of a planned 20 books (if I recall correctly). I've  perused it myself, but no more than that.